# javascript value to input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a plugin that I am trying to grab the the number of the current slide which will then be written to a input box with the ID of "input1" each time the slide is changed. Does my syntax make sense?

```
function currentSlide(){
    var current = $('#slider').data('AnythingSlider').currentPage; 
    document.getElementById("input1").innerHTML=current;
};
```

Comment: You could replace document.getElementById("input1").innerHTML=current; by $("#input1").html(current); besides that it's hard to tell without the html source...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `input1` is an input (as the name implies) use:

```
document.getElementById("input1").value = current;
```

Or to use jQuery only:

```
function currentSlide(){
    var current = $('#slider').data('AnythingSlider').currentPage; 
    $("#input1").val(current);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to change what is shown in an `<input>` elemnt, set the `.value`, NOT the `.innerHTML`.

Think about it. Do you write `<input>Blah blah blah</input>`, or do you write `<input value="Blah blah blah" />`? JavaScript treats elements the same way HTML does.

Answer (score 0):

```
function currentSlide(){
  var current = $('#slider').data('AnythingSlider').currentPage; 
  $('input1').val(current);
};
```

If you're using jQuery, I recommend sticking with jQuery selectors throughout your code. I've updated line 3 to use jQuery to select `input1`. Instead of using `innerHTML`, use jQuery's `val` function which will set `input1`'s value to the `current`string.